# What happens to SignalR messages that go over the limit, are they ignored or in a queue?

Tags: azure, queue, signalr, signalr-hub

Hello I was doing some testing and following this site for SignalR limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-performance

My question is.  **When I go over the allotted amount of messages per second does it go to a queue that handles it in the next second or should I use another alternative like Servicebus?**

I was doing some testing and seeing this section where for broadcast type messages per second is always 2:

```
Broadcast                   Unit1   Unit2   Unit5   Unit10  Unit20  Unit50  Unit100
Connections                 1,000   2,000   5,000   10,000  20,000  50,000  100,000
Inbound messages per second 2       2       2       2       2       2       2
```

From the testing I was doing I cannot see anything error out so I was not seeing in the reading what happens when I have a 3rd message.  It appears it just goes into a queue?  That I cannot see and then processes it in the proceeding second.